# use get_posts to get custom field data, but in one array

Tags: custom-field, get-posts, array

I've run a get_posts query in WordPress and need to pull a pair of custom fields and get all of them into one array. The get_posts query provides an array of posts, but when I use foreach to access the custom fields, I end up with separate arrays for each result.

**The Query**

```
$c_query = get_posts(
                    array(
                        'post_type' => 'page',
                        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                        'meta_key' => 'concert_date',
                        'meta_query' => array(

                            array(
                                'key'   => '_wp_page_template', 
                                'value' => array('rock.php', 'pop.php', 'jazz.php'),
                                'compare' => 'IN'
                            )
                            array(
                              'key'   => 'concert_date'
                              'value'  => date('m/d/Y')
                            )

                         )
                    )
                );
```

**Foreach**

To access the concert date, I used foreach:

```
foreach($c_query as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 

        $c_query['concert_date'] = $concert_date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),
 'concert_date', true);
        $c_query['concert_city'] = $concert_date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),
 'concert_city', true); 

endforeach;
```

and the result pulls the correct data, but I get separate arrays for each concert date and city pair (because of foreach):

**Resulting Arrays**

```
 Array ( [0] => 01-11-2012 [1] => New York) 
 Array ( [0] => 03-23-2013 [1] => Boston) 
 Array ( [0] => 06-09-2014 [1] => London)
```

What can I do to get these result arrays into one big array? Trying to get an array of the concert date and city pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter your foreach loop as following to get concert date and city pair in single multidimentional array as following.

```
$concert_query = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($c_query as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 

    $concert_query[$i]['concert_date'] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'concert_date', true);
    $concert_query[$i]['concert_city'] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'concert_city', true); 
    $i ++;
endforeach;

print_r($concert_query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to setup post data on `$post` each time. You already have the post ID and `get_post_meta()` does not depend on the `$post` variable.

```
$concerts = array();

foreach ( $c_query as $concert ) {
    $concerts[] = array(
        'concert_date' => get_post_meta( $concert->ID, 'concert_date', true ),
        'concert_city' => get_post_meta( $concert->ID, 'concert_city', true ),
    );
}
```