# How to associate 2 custom fields together (date & price for instance)?

Tags: custom-field

On my website you can purchase a trip after choosing the departure date (among the available departure dates). In the back-end, a trip is a CPT in which departure dates are specified through "Repeater Field" (an extension of "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin).

Trip price depends on departure date so each departure date must have a trip price attached to it. How can I have a price field next to each date field?

I'd prefer to use those plugins but I'm open to any suggestion.

EDIT: I came across [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111576/use-get-posts-to-get-custom-field-data-but-in-one-array) that looks related to my problem, but I don't understand the code in it.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, how about dynamic meta-key : 'departure-1', 'departure-2','departure-3'. And another 2 cents : serialized / json encoded meta value : {"departure":"12:00", "price":100}

Comment: Not sure to follow you, please explain further. Also how would that look like in dashboard CPT edit screen?

Comment: Please take a look at this framework http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#have_fields_and_multi. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ACF, in the same repeater custom field that your departure date uses, add a price field. Then each time you add a departure date, you can add the associated price. Wherever you're showing the departure date in the template you can add the price field as well.

Comment: Hadn't thought about adding more than one sub-field, this plugin is really awesome! Thanks a lot Christopher.